# Implications for Using eval() in Windows Store App Game API

Tags: javascript, security, windows-store-apps, eval

I'm developing a Windows Store App game and am currently working on implementing a framework for a modding API. I want modders to be able to write various scripts in JavaScript that will have access to various contexts within the game. For example, they could manipulate the "stage" variable to add game entities and so forth.

I'd prefer not to have to create or use some other scripting language (like Python for example) to accomplish the task. The game itself is written in JavaScript and I want to give potential modders the ability to use JavaScript as their modding language because many people will already have good familiarity with it.

I understand there are security implications for using eval in JavaScript, but since the eval'd code would be running in the same security context that my app itself is running in, I fail to see any real issue with opening up the "eval doors" for this specific purpose.

However, I want to be sure I have as much information as possible before I go forward with using eval. Which is what led me here. So without further adieu:

**What are the potential implications (security or otherwise) for using eval inside a Windows Store App game?**

I'll accept any links to helpful sources as a sufficient answer.